# .Net MVC Repository Pattern with EF throwing Error (Local threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I am getting below error from objContext.warrantys property of entity framework.

Error Message:A null was returned after calling the 'get_ProviderFactory' method on a store provider instance of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection'. The store provider might not be functioning correctly.

`Local  'objContext.warrantys.Local' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'     System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<DSGWarrantyServiceRep.Core.warranty> {System.InvalidOperationException}`

In Web.config,

```
public class warranty
{

    public int WarrantyId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessage =" Please provide Warrranty Name")]
    [MinLength(4)]
    public string WarrantyName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = " Please provide Warrranty Period")]
    public string WarrantyPeriod
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = " Please provide UPC Nbr")]
    public string UpcNbr
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public warranty()
    {
    }
}
```

Now, I am going to add dbcontext class.

```
public class WarrantyContext:DbContext
{
    public WarrantyContext() : base("name=warrantyConnectionString")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<warranty> warrantys { get; set; }
}
```

Now From My warranty service class implemented here

```
public class WarrantyService : IWarrantyService
{
    WarrantyContext objContext = new WarrantyContext();

    public void AddWarranty(warranty ws)
    {

        objContext.warrantys.Add(ws);
        objContext.SaveChanges();
    }
   public IEnumerable<warranty> GetAllWarranty()
    {
        **return objContext.warrantys;**
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't use `objContext.warrantys.Local` in the code you show, nor do you show the code that causes the error.

Comment: I am not using objContext.warrantys.Local. I am getting above said error from objContext.warrantys under GetAllWarranty() function.

Comment: I'll try to rephrase my question. `GetAllWarranty()` only returns a query. It doesn't *execute* it. So my question is: where do you call the `GetAllWarranty()` method in a way that the error is thrown? It seems pretty absurd that a call to `objContext.warrantys` also tries to access the `Local` collection.

Comment: Hey All,  The problem with Excel calling. I have shifted to Sql server and same code is running absolutely fine.  Thank you every one... Appreacite your help to find out the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you need to check your connection string in the web.config (web app) or app.config (other). Feel free to post it here too. You seem to be using the OLEDB, and you should be using native SqlClient instead.

You should have something that looks like this (local db in this case, but could be SQL for you), for example:

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="warrantyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-TestApp1-20170112094217.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-TestApp1-20170112094217;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I have modified my connection string  .   <add name="warrantyConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=..,Data\EF.mdb;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>  I am getting below error:  An error occurred accessing the database. This usually means that the connection to the database failed. Check that the connection string is correct and that the appropriate DbContext constructor is being used to specify it or find it in the application's config file.  Inner Exception Message: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.

Comment: You're still using a connection string provider formatted to OLEDB. Are you trying to connect to a MS Access file or something?

If you're connecting to a SQL Server, your connection string entry should look like:


             `<add name="WarrantyDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=ServerName\SQLServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Comment: If this is the case, you may need to [look at other resources to bridge the gap](https://jetentityframeworkprovider.codeplex.com/)